# GridBagLayout not arranging JPanels as expected

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a simple Swing app, which looks as follows:

[image]

Each set of components that has a border around it, is a single `JPanel`. I'm using a `GridBagLayout`. The problem I encounter is that they are not being arranged as desired. I want to have the following layout:

[image]

I'm using the following code:

```
public class Window extends JFrame
{
    public Window()
    {
        // set window properties
        this.setTitle("My Automotive");
        this.setSize(this.WINDOW_WIDTH, this.WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        this._panel = new JPanel();
        this._panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        this._oilAndLubePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Oil and Lube"));
        this._oilAndLubePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this._oilAndLubePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this._oilAndLubePanel.add(this._oilChangeCb);
        this._oilAndLubePanel.add(this._lubeJobCb);
        addGroup(this._oilAndLubePanel, 0, 0);
        
        this._flushesPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Flushes"));
        this._flushesPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this._flushesPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this._flushesPanel.add(this._radiatorFlushCb);
        this._flushesPanel.add(this._transmissionFlushCb);
        addGroup(this._flushesPanel, 1, 0);
        
        this._miscPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Misc"));
        this._miscPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this._miscPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this._miscPanel.add(this._inspectionCb);
        this._miscPanel.add(this._replaceMufflerCb);
        this._miscPanel.add(this._tireRotationCb);
        addGroup(this._miscPanel, 0, 1);
        
        this._partsAndLabourPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Parts and Labour"));
        this._partsAndLabourPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this._partsAndLabourPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this._partsAndLabourPanel.add(this._partsFieldLbl);
        this._partsAndLabourPanel.add(this._partsField);
        this._partsAndLabourPanel.add(this._labourFieldLbl);
        this._partsAndLabourPanel.add(this._labourField);
        addGroup(this._partsAndLabourPanel, 1, 1);
        
        this._summaryPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Summary"));
        this._summaryPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.addComponentToSummaryPanel(this._servicesAndLabourFieldLbl, 0, 0);
        this._servicesAndLabourField.setEditable(false);
        this.addComponentToSummaryPanel(this._servicesAndLabourField, 1, 0);
        this.addComponentToSummaryPanel(this._partsSummaryFieldLbl, 0, 1);
        this._partsSummaryField.setEditable(false);
        this.addComponentToSummaryPanel(this._partsSummaryField, 1, 1);
        this.addComponentToSummaryPanel(this._taxFielLbl, 0, 2);
        this._taxField.setEditable(false);
        this.addComponentToSummaryPanel(this._taxField, 1, 2);
        this.addComponentToSummaryPanel(this._totalFeesFieldLbl, 0, 3);
        this._totalFeesField.setEditable(false);
        this.addComponentToSummaryPanel(this._totalFeesField, 1, 3);
        addGroup(this._summaryPanel, 0, 2);
        
        this.add(this._panel);
        
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addGroup(JPanel panel,
            int gridx, int gridy)
    {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1; // use all horizontal space available
        gbc.weighty = 1; // use all vertical space available
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = gridx;
        gbc.gridy = gridy;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2,2,2,2);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        
        this._panel.add(panel);
    }
}
```

Why is the desired layout not being achieved, and how to fix it?

Comment: If all the named panels should be the same size, and the name can be part of a titled border, then this is [easy to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdOyS.png) using a `GridLayout`. Though it's also possible to do with a `GridBagLayout`, it is not as simple. **General Tip:** For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes I've thought about using `GridLayout`. However, I am still curious as to this behaviour. I have tried it using other types of components, and they are arranged as expected in the appropriate cells. It's only with the `JPanel` components that this occurs. Why is it the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no good defining the constraint if it's not used when adding the component! So:

```
this._panel.add(panel);
```

Should be:

```
this._panel.add(panel, gbc);
```